# After hard drive died, DVD drive isn't recognized anymore

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, installation, crash

My computer was running Vista until my hard drive crashed, so I bought a new 2TB internal SATA HDD.

And now my DVD drive isn't being recongized by my BIOS, but my new 2TB HDD is. I think it has to do with the IDE ports, so I'm buying a SATA DVD drive. Will this solve my problem?

Comment: Well, plug it in and see if it works.

Answer (score 2):

IDE controllers are able to connect two devices at a time with the option to use a Master/Slave connection protocol. On all IDE drives, there are a set of pins on the back with a jumper connecting two pins to enable that switch. If your old IDE hard drive was set to master and the DVD to slave, when you removed the hard drive without changing the DVD's jumper to "CS" (for cable select) or Master/Single.

In addition, some older machines have BIOS that do not auto detect drive types or lack of. So the BIOS might have to be explicitly set for just the DVD (as master) and no device as the slave. (disabled).

Lastly, be sure to use the end socket on the IDE cable (usually marked Master), not the middle socket, with the controller end on the motherboard (check that its not reversed).